# Unmet dependencies error while installing npm

Tags: node.js, npm

When I try to install npm package I am getting unmet dependencies error.

```
sudo apt-get install npm
```

I removed usr/lib/node_modules directory and try to reinstall but I am getting same error. Is there any way to handle this?

I am using linux Mint 18.3.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
npm : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-abbrev (>= 1.0.4) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-ansi (>= 0.3.0-2) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-ansi-color-table but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-archy but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-block-stream but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-fstream (>= 0.1.22) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-fstream-ignore but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-github-url-from-git but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-glob (>= 3.1.21) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-graceful-fs (>= 2.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-inherits but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-ini (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-lockfile but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-lru-cache (>= 2.3.0) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-minimatch (>= 0.2.11) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-mkdirp (>= 0.3.3) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-gyp (>= 0.10.9) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-nopt (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-npmlog but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-once but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-osenv but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-read but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-read-package-json (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-request (>= 2.25.0) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-retry but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-rimraf (>= 2.2.2) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-semver (>= 2.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-sha but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-slide but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-tar (>= 0.1.18) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-underscore but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-which but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: The install command is `$ sudo apt update && sudo apt install npm`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just uninstall npm and download node from [Node JS](https://nodejs.org/en/)

Then try to install npm and node again.

I solved same dependency error with re-install.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you have by mistake deleted python 2.7.x which is required. Just reinstall node.js and npm using this link  and you should be good